# Why are there spaces on the left and right hand side of my seekbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, seekbar

I am working on `Seekbar` and i have found one issue. A default space is present on the left and right hand side. I need the seekbar to be full width. I did `match_parent` and `fill_parent` but that didn't work.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <SeekBar
      android:id="@+id/seek_bar_controller"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="0dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

You can follow this snapshot for the reference, on both left and right hand sides space is present.

Please kindly go through my post and suggest some solution.

Comment: The padding can come from the parent element as well.

Comment: I think It is default property of `SeekBar` as the thumb uses that extra padding.. I think you should give minus margin to `SeekBar` from both hand. check out

Comment: share your parent xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove that you need to use `android:thumbOffset="20dp"`,

try below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar_controller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:thumbOffset="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seek_bar_controller"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
/* In your activity */
SeekBar seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_controller);
seekBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Even the accepted answer also did not work for me. This has works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the XML below, it worked for me:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <SeekBar
          android:id="@+id/seek_bar_controller"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:thumbOffset="10dp"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
         android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove extra space from the left and right of the seekbar. Use the below code.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
     android:id="@+id/distanceSeekBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginHorizontal="-23dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8"
     android:indeterminate="false"
     android:paddingStart="0dp"
     android:paddingEnd="0dp"
     android:splitTrack="false"
     android:thumbOffset="0dp"
     android:elevation="4dp"
     android:progress="0"
     android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_background"
     android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"/>
```